# Try/Except - Stop After Finding Result

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, try-except

So currently my scraper script works pretty well with pulling data from devices.  I am mostly using this script to detect all my printers on the network and then to update the database with my findings.  I know the code might not be 100% clean, since I am still learning and enhancing my Python skills, but I have a quick question that I am sure someone can answer quickly.  I feel like I should know this but I am having a loss of thought on it. :/

Is there a way that after my script finds a result to stop the script from running the other functions?

For example:  If printer_a() finds a match and prints back the result of the printer, or whatever device it saw, is there a way to stop the script from running and continue on the next IP address?  It appears right now that even after getting the result...it continues on the other functions.  I have tried many other variations with the code below, but I can't seem to figure this bugger out.  Any help would me most appreciated.  Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys

ipaddress_input = raw_input("IP Address? ")

#header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

def printer_a():
    printer_address_a = str("http://" + ipaddress_input)
    printer_request_a = urllib2.Request(printer_address_a,headers=header)
    printer_page_a = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_a,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_a = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_a)
    printer_find_a = printer_soup_a.find("title")
    printer_string_a = str(printer_find_a)
    printer_result_a = printer_string_a[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_a) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_a

def printer_b():
    printer_address_b = str("http://" + ipaddress_input + "/default.asp?Lang=en-us")
    printer_request_b = urllib2.Request(printer_address_b,headers=header)
    printer_page_b = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_b,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_b = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_b)
    printer_find_b = printer_soup_b.find("title")
    printer_string_b = str(printer_find_b)
    printer_result_b = printer_string_b[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_b) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_b

def printer_c():
    printer_address_c = str("http://" + ipaddress_input + "/default.html")
    printer_request_c = urllib2.Request(printer_address_c,headers=header)
    printer_page_c = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_c,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_c = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_c)
    printer_find_c = printer_soup_c.find("title")
    printer_string_c = str(printer_find_c)
    printer_result_c = printer_string_c[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_c) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_c

def printer_d():
    printer_address_d = str("https://" + ipaddress_input + "/cgi-bin/f_cgi")
    printer_request_d = urllib2.Request(printer_address_d,headers=header)
    printer_page_d = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_d,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_d = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_d)
    printer_find_d = printer_soup_d.find("title")
    printer_string_d = str(printer_find_d)
    printer_result_d = printer_string_d[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_d) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_d

def printer_e():
    printer_address_e = str("http://" + ipaddress_input + "/login.html")
    printer_request_e = urllib2.Request(printer_address_e,headers=header)
    printer_page_e = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_e,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_e = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_e)
    printer_find_e = printer_soup_e.find("title")
    printer_string_e = str(printer_find_e)
    printer_result_e = printer_string_e[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_e) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_e

def printer_f():
    printer_address_f = str("https://" + ipaddress_input)
    printer_request_f = urllib2.Request(printer_address_f,headers=header)
    printer_page_f = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_f,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_f = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_f)
    printer_find_f = printer_soup_f.find("title")
    printer_string_f = str(printer_find_f)
    printer_result_f = printer_string_f[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_f) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_f

def printer_g():
    printer_address_g = str("http://" + ipaddress_input + "/main/main.html")
    printer_request_g = urllib2.Request(printer_address_g,headers=header)
    printer_page_g = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request_g,timeout=5)
    printer_soup_g = BeautifulSoup(printer_page_g)
    printer_find_g = printer_soup_g.find("title")
    printer_string_g = str(printer_find_g)
    fixed = "".join(printer_string_g.split())
    printer_result_g = fixed[7:-8]
    if len(printer_result_g) < 2:
        quit()
    print printer_result_g

try:
    printer_g()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_a()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_b()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_c()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_d()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_e()
except:
    pass
try:
    printer_f()
except:
    pass
```

Edit:  Here's the new code I came up with.  It appears to be working and is a lot cleaner.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys

ipaddress_input = raw_input("IP Address? ")

#header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

addresses = ["/main/main.html", "/hp/device/this.LCDispatcher", "/default.asp?Lang=en-us", "/default.html", "/cgi-bin/f_cgi", "/login.html", ""]
printer_name_oce = "Oce"
printer_name_hp = "hp"
for url_end in addresses:
    try:
        printer_address = str("http://" + ipaddress_input) + url_end
        printer_request = urllib2.Request(printer_address,headers=header)
        printer_page = urllib2.urlopen(printer_request,timeout=7)
        printer_soup = BeautifulSoup(printer_page)
        printer_find = printer_soup.find("title")
        printer_string = str(printer_find)
        printer_result = printer_string[7:-8]
        if printer_name_oce in printer_string:
            fixed = ''.join(printer_string.split())
            printer_result = fixed[7:-8]
            print printer_result
            if len(printer_result) > 2:
                break
        if printer_name_hp in printer_string:
            fixed = ''.join(printer_string.split())
            printer_result = fixed[7:-8]
            print printer_result
            if len(printer_result) > 2:
                break
        if len(printer_result) < 2:
            quit()
        print printer_result
        if len(printer_result) > 2:
            break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have 7 almost-completely-identical functions? That's an immediate sanction from the Redundancy Department of Redundancy. Make the end of the URL a *parameter*, and call the same function with different values. Then you can loop over these: `for url_end in ('', '/default.asp?Lang=en-us', ...):` and `break` once one matches. Also, **don't use bare `except:`**; what error(s) are you expecting?

Comment: I think you need a scraper for your scraper...  I'm a bit bewildered myself at the code, why the need for that structure(?), and/or what the difference is between each of those `defs` o_O

Comment: I was going to clean up the redundancy once I had the code working and I could see where the issues were lying...sort of like a print statement.  It was just part of my debugging I was doing. :/ Don't be too harsh on me. I will definitely clean it up and try the loop and that does make sense on that working better.

Comment: Well...I cleaned the code up and this appears to work how I want it to.  Any improvements you can think of for those that were harsh? lol